# How to enhance this small script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main div, and div's inside the main div, all the div's that are inside the main div are classed with .testimonial, each div of testimonial have an image inside it...

What I wanted to is:
When hover-over one of the images, all of the images inside the div will have an opacity of 60% for example and the selected image will keep it's 100% opacity. By using the script below everything is working great. However I was wondering if there is a better way to do it? or to enhance the script below? The only reason I am asking is because as you can see in the script below, there are TWO functions to do the job! can't we make it only one?

```
//Testimonials Animation//
    $(".testimonial, .plan").hover(function () {
        $(".testimonial, .plan").addClass('itemNotActive');
        $(this).removeClass('itemNotActive').addClass('itemActive');
    },

    function () {
        $(".testimonial, .plan").removeClass('itemNotActive');
        $(this).removeClass('itemActive');
    });
```

Comment: hover is supposed to be 2 functions, mouseover and mouseout

Comment: not sure why you need to add a not active class. Normally, the not active is the default state, so you could only override the needed styles by itemActive, instead of having two classes, one for each distinct state.

Comment: Not in my case, for a live preview please go here: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/index.php that how it is working now, i just need a better script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the reason you have both `active` and `notActive` is because they both have special styles. You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9tr72/

```
$('.testimonial').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.testimonial').not(this).addClass('not-active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.testimonial').removeClass('active not-active');
});
```

Even so, it only saved one line. You have different things that need to happen for each event, so you need two handlers.

Comment: Not much different of what I have but will use it, may i ask why did you use mouseenter and mouselave?

Comment: @Loai For some reason, I thought that `hover` was deprecated, but the docs say otherwise. Either way, `hover` is shorthand for what I have, and I tend to use `.on('event', function(){...})` as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is what you are wanting. All testimonials are at default state (itemActive) until you hover and nothing but the hovered item has itemActive applied. Now make your itemNotActive the default state.

```
$(".testimonial, .plan").hover(function () {
    $(".testimonial:not("+this+")").removeClass('itemActive');
}, function () {
    $(".testimonial").addClass('itemActive');
});
```

Comment: That is applying the Active style to the selected image, but not applying the notActive style to all the other images.

Comment: So the default is that all of the images has 100% opacity and no shadow. But when you hover over an image, the selected image will have shadow, and all the other images will have 50% opacity and so on, like how it is working on the live link above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".testimonial, .plan").hover(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('itemNotActive').addClass('itemActive');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('itemActive').addClass('itemNotActive');;
    });
```

Comment: Not working properly mate, for a live test go here: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/index.php and scroll down to the testimonial section.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would do first is cache the jQuery. But apart form that, since there are two different events that do two different things, you need two functions. Even if you had a hybrid function that handled both events, there would be no point, it would only obfuscate the code.

```
var hoverBoxes = $(".testimonial, .plan");
hoverBoxes.hover(
    function () {
        hoverBoxes.not(this).addClass('itemNotActive');
        $(this).addClass('itemActive');
    },
    function () {
       hoverBoxes.removeClass('itemActive').removeClass('itemNotActive');
    });
);
```